# About provable-recursive functions in EA

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Find $\forall$-axiomatisation of definitional extension of EA with functional symbols for all Kalmar elementary functions. Then use Herbrand's theorem to find the class of provable-recursive functions in EA.

I know that class of provable-recursive functions is stable over $\Pi_1$-extensions. But how will Herbrand's theorem help?
(sorry, i've just started exploring proof-theory)